# Count lines of a table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count the lines of a table and put the result in a PHP table.
But, I have a lil problem.

My code :

```
$reponse = $bdd->query('SHOW TABLES FROM '.$db_name);
    echo '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped ">';
            echo'<thead>
                  <th class="text-center">Name</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Numbers of lines</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Show columns</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Rename</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Delete</th>
                 </thead>';
            echo'<tbody>';
            ?>

    <?php
   while($value = $reponse->fetch())
{
    $table = $value[$i];
    echo '<tr><td class="col-db text-center">'.$table.'</td>';

    $rep = $bdd->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '.$table);
    $data = $rep->fetch();

    var_dump($data, $rep);
    echo'<td class="col-db text-center">'.$data.'</td>';
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLaqP.png)

But my table is like this normaly without error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba9PJ.png)

Comment: Why not just use a [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to count your number of rows

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to loop over all rows to do this, you can just use a count query:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM table
```

The first row in this result will have the amount of rows in this table.

Comment: Sidenote: `count(*)` isn't always a good idea. If their table isn't properly indexed and/or they have a lot of records, then counting all rows stands to be slow. So, counting `COUNT(col)` may work better.

Comment: @Fred-ii- _count(*) isn't always a good idea_ What is the better idea?

Comment: @bub either choose/count the column(s) or php's `count()` as stated in comments under the answer. My comment up here was edited btw.

Comment: Look at my latest answer please @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Jerodev parles tu français, je serai peut-être plus clair pour expliquer ma problématique ? :)